# how to remove the white space while navigating from one view to other view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i am having navigation bar hidden in my fist view-A and want to show it on other view-B.
but when i come back from View-B to view-A,I am getting some white space on view-B before coming to View-A.

How can i stop getting that white space?

Comment: Use `- [NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];`

Comment: I think he is seeing white pixels, not a string whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the navigation bar later, after view-B is gone. You can use `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:` in view-A's `viewDidAppear` method.